# iphone configurable menu like facebook app

Tags: iphone, facebook, menu

Im just wanting to know what control to use to mimic the editable menu like the facebook app menu (i.e. 3*3 buttons and the user can click and hold on the menu and it will than allow them to edit the menu by dragging and dropping the buttons around the screen).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Three 20 has the TTLauncher control which allows you to do this very easily.